# Computer_Architecture + Verilog

Tags: verilog, cpu-architecture

I am doing a divider circuit in verilog and using the non-restoring division algorithm.
I am having trouble representing the remainder as a fractional binary number.
For example if I do 0111/0011 (7/3) I get the quotient as 0010 and remainder as 0001 which is correct but I want to represent it as 0010.0101.
Can Someone help ??

Comment: 7/3 =2.33333... I understand that in quotient 2 means 0010 (which is binary of 2) how do you represent the .3333 part as (0001) as you said it in your question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose, as in your example, you are dividing 4 bit numbers, but want an extra 4 bits of fractional precision in the result.

One approach is to simply multiply the numerator by 2^4 before doing the division.

i.e.

```
instead of 
0111/0011 = 0010 (+remainder)
do
01110000/0011 = 00100101 (+remainder)
```

Answer (score 0):

hi just do mathematics !!!

you have already got the Q(quotient) and R(remainder) , now with the remainder you multiply that with 10(decimal) in binary 1010 that for example 
7/3 gives 2 as Q and 1 as remainder than just multiply this 1 with 10 then again apply your logic which gives 10/3 gives 3 as Q so your answer will be 
3(Q(first_division)).3(second division-Q)

try it it is working . and very easy to implement in verilog .